# PHPStorm rename remote files failing

Tags: symfony, debian, phpstorm

I am using PHPStorm 8.0.1.
I am working on a Symfony Project which runs on an nginx webserver on a debian system.

I have set up Automatic Deployment correctly and everything works very well, except of renaming the remote files.

PHPStorm fails with the message: "Failed to rename file 'filename.extension' to 'filename.extension': could not determine if file 'path to file' is writeable. (Could not get the groups id of the current user (error code: 1))

Can Anybody here point me in the direction on how to solve this error?

Comment: Seems like a permissions issue with the path.

Comment: That was my first thought too. but i checked it, and the owner of the path is my sftp user which is also set up for deployment in phpstorm. so i think that shout work.

Comment: Check your Event Log tool window content. Also PhpStorm log can be helpful: Help -> Show log

Comment: thanks for your tip Kootli, but i couldnt find anything in the logs :( searched for exact date and time but didnt found anything

Comment: 1) Update your IDE to latest version (8.0.2 is latest stable and 8.0.3 is latest EAP); 2) Enable more detailed deployment logging: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202

Comment: Thanks LazyOne, will do it.

Comment: Finally was able to solve it. 
For anybody who has this troubles too: 

Check your ssh users permissions. In my case it was that i set up a chroot directory for this user which was causing the problems. 

After removing the chrooting it works fine and i could rename the files. 
Thanks everybody for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Reason: chroot enabled (thanks BloodandDeath for comment). In my Hestia panel settings, I just switched the SSH user setting from nologin to bash, after which PHPStorm started renaming files without error. By the way, everything worked well in Filezilla without changing the settings, which suggests a bug in PHPStorm ...